# Чем и как собирать OpenCL?

Tags: c++, cmake, mingw, opencl

Уже долгое время пытаюсь собрать OpenCL, но ниче не получается.
Сначала я скачиваю исходники https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenCL-SDK и с помощью CMake (ничего не настраивая) собираю это всё (предварительно установив в нём компилятор, соответствующей версии). Далее я пытаюсь собрать это с помощью mingw (mingw32-make.exe) версий: 8.1.0 (x64, x32), 10.3.0 (x32, x64)

При этом я получаю следующие ошибки:

Для версии mingw32(и 64) 10.3.0, если собирать в CMake как для mingw32 8.1.0 (см. ниже почему именно так):

> C:\Users\Public\Documents\Qt_Projects\warm-up1\opencl\build>D:\msys64\mingw32\bi
> n\mingw32-make.exe [  2%] Building C object
> external/OpenCL-ICD-Loader/CMakeFiles/OpenCL.dir/loader /icd.c.obj In
> file included from
> C:/Users/Public/Documents/Qt_Projects/warm-up1/opencl/sour
> ce/external/OpenCL-Headers/CL/cl_platform.h:244,
> from C:/Users/Public/Documents/Qt_Projects/warm-up1/opencl/sour
> ce/external/OpenCL-Headers/CL/cl.h:21,
> from C:\Users\Public\Documents\Qt_Projects\warm-up1\opencl\sour
> ce\external\OpenCL-ICD-Loader\loader\icd.h:36,
> from C:\Users\Public\Documents\Qt_Projects\warm-up1\opencl\sour
> ce\external\OpenCL-ICD-Loader\loader\icd.c:19:
> D:/msys64/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/include/stdint.h:9:16:
> fatal e rror: stdint.h: No such file or directory
> 9 | # include_next <stdint.h>
> |                ^~~~~~~~~~ compilation terminated. mingw32-make[2]: ***
> [external\OpenCL-ICD-Loader\CMakeFiles\OpenCL.dir\build.mak e:76:
> external/OpenCL-ICD-Loader/CMakeFiles/OpenCL.dir/loader/icd.c.obj]
> Error 1 mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:295:
> external/OpenCL-ICD-Loader/CMake Files/OpenCL.dir/all] Error 2
> mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:135: all] Error 2

В интернете ничего по поводу этой ошибки я не нашёл.

Для версии mingw32 (и 64) 8.1.0:

> C:\Users\Public\Documents\Qt_Projects\warm-up1\opencl\build>"D:\mingw64_810\bin
> mingw32-make.exe" Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of
> target OpenCL [  2%] Building C object
> external/OpenCL-ICD-Loader/CMakeFiles/OpenCL.dir/loader
> /windows/icd_windows_hkr.c.obj
> C:\Users\Public\Documents\Qt_Projects\warm-up1\opencl\source\external\OpenCL-ICD
> -Loader\loader\windows\icd_windows_hkr.c: In function 'khrIcdOsVendorsEnumerateH KR':
> C:\Users\Public\Documents\Qt_Projects\warm-up1\opencl\source\external\OpenCL-ICD
> -Loader\loader\windows\icd_windows_hkr.c:217:21: error: 'CM_GETIDLIST_FILTER_CLA SS' undeclared (first use in this function);
> did you mean 'CM_GETIDLIST_FILTER_B ITS'?   217 |     ULONG ulFlags =
> CM_GETIDLIST_FILTER_CLASS |
> |                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> |                     CM_GETIDLIST_FILTER_BITS C:\Users\Public\Documents\Qt_Projects\warm-up1\opencl\source\external\OpenCL-ICD
> -Loader\loader\windows\icd_windows_hkr.c:217:21: note: each undeclared identifie r is reported only once for each function it appears in
> C:\Users\Public\Documents\Qt_Projects\warm-up1\opencl\source\external\OpenCL-ICD
> -Loader\loader\windows\icd_windows_hkr.c:218:21: error: 'CM_GETIDLIST_FILTER_PRE SENT' undeclared (first use in this
> function); did you mean 'CM_GETIDLIST_FILTER
> _BITS'?   218 |                     CM_GETIDLIST_FILTER_PRESENT;
> |                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> |                     CM_GETIDLIST_FILTER_BITS C:\Users\Public\Documents\Qt_Projects\warm-up1\opencl\source\external\OpenCL-ICD
> -Loader\loader\windows\icd_windows_hkr.c:343:22: error: 'DEVPKEY_Device_ClassGui d' undeclared (first use in this function)
> 343 |                     &DEVPKEY_Device_ClassGuid,
> |                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ mingw32-make[2]: *** [external\OpenCL-ICD-Loader\CMakeFiles\OpenCL.dir\build.mak e:166: external/OpenCL-ICD-Loader/CMakeFiles/OpenCL.dir/loader/windows/icd_windo
> ws_hkr.c.obj] Error 1 mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:295:
> external/OpenCL-ICD-Loader/CMake Files/OpenCL.dir/all] Error 2
> mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:135: all] Error 2

Здесь уже информации побольше. Вот тут https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenCL-ICD-Loader/issues/130 советуют установить более новую версию mingw. Но выше я уже пробовал так делать.

Если я пытаюсь конфигурировать проект с помощью mingw32 версии 10.3.0 из под msys2 с установленными пакетами (для 32):

mingw-w64-x86_32-gcc

mingw-w64-x86_32-gcc-libs

mingw-w64-x86_32-make

То CMake ругаца:

> Check for working C compiler: D:/msys64/mingw32/bin/gcc.exe - broken
> CMake Error at D:/Program Files/CMake
> 3.20.2/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:66 (message):   The C compiler
>
> ```
> "D:/msys64/mingw32/bin/gcc.exe"
> ```
>
> is not able to compile a simple test program.
>
> It fails with the following output:
>
> ```
> Change Dir: C:/Users/Public/Documents/Qt_Projects/warm-up1/opencl/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
>
> Run Build Command(s):D:/mingw64/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f Makefile cmTC_64f2b/fast && D:/mingw64/bin/mingw32-make.exe  -f
> ```
>
> CMakeFiles\cmTC_64f2b.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_64f2b.dir/build
>
> ```
> mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/Public/Documents/Qt_Projects/warm-up1/opencl/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
>
> Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_64f2b.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj
>
> D:\msys64\mingw32\bin\gcc.exe    -o CMakeFiles\cmTC_64f2b.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj -c
> ```
>
> C:\Users\Public\Documents\Qt_Projects\warm-up1\opencl\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCCompiler.c
>
> ```
> C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\cc6VTnLT.s: Assembler messages:
>
> C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\cc6VTnLT.s:9: Error: invalid instruction suffix for `push'
>
> CMakeFiles\cmTC_64f2b.dir\build.make:76: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_64f2b.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj' failed
>
> mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_64f2b.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj] Error 1
>
> mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/Public/Documents/Qt_Projects/warm-up1/opencl/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
>
> Makefile:126: recipe for target 'cmTC_64f2b/fast' failed
>
> mingw32-make.exe: *** [cmTC_64f2b/fast] Error 2
> ```

Для x64 дополнительно ещё просит libgmp-10.dll. Очень просит. Диалоговое окно нужно протыкать раз десять, чтобы оно исчезло.

Установка пакета mingw-w64-x86_64-gmp ничего не даёт.

Так какой же версией мне это собирать?

Comment: Используя версию mingw 11.2.0 с сайта https://winlibs.com/ и флаги OPENCL_ICD_LOADER_DISABLE_OPENCLON12=ON (иначе начинает снова просить windows.management.deployment.h, хотя на компьютере и установлена последняя версия Windows SDK в которой он есть), и BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF, иначе member CMakeFiles\OpenCL.dir/objects.a(OpenCL.rc.obj) in archive is not an object collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status. После этого сборка проходит успешно!

Comment: Но теперь появляется другая проблема: ошибка: windows.management.deployment.h: No such file or directory, хотя опять же этот файл есть в Windows SDK.

Comment: К проекту я подключаю как обычно:

add_subdirectory(opencl/source)
target_link_libraries(warm_up1 OpenCL)
add_subdirectory(opencl/source/external/OpenCL-Headers)